# No sound on ASUS 1225C notebook with pre-installed 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, sound

Sound works fine on first operation. However, after doing a complete update sound is lost. Solutions presented on Ask Ubuntu up to now do NOT work. Only solution for the moment is to return to factory settings losing all personal files and downloaded updates. This "NO SOUND" problem seems to be major. Any ideas anyone ? Your help would be much appreciated by thousands of users world-wide !

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. Following the advice given in lindis comment doesn't help at all: alsa-hda-dkms isn't present.

Here how I get it to work: I removed dkms ( `apt-get remove dkms` ).Then I've rebooted (graphics are disabled, it's text only mode); I've reinstalled dkms ( `apt-get update ;apt-get install dkms`) then started X (`startx`); from there I reinstalled the proprietary driver using the driver utility (I don't know how to run it from the command line though I suppose there's some CLI utility to achieve the same result).

After another reboot both sound and graphics work properly.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your system is up-to-date. Then you may be hit by [bug 1037763](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1037763). Here is a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1037763/comments/10) proposed by [lindis](https://launchpad.net/~gross6):

- Open Terminal
- write this command:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```

  This command opens the program Gedit: now you can modify the file `sources.list`.
  Add to the file the lines:

  ```
  deb http://asus.archive.canonical.com/updates precise-yanshui public
  deb-src http://asus.archive.canonical.com/updates precise-yanshui public
  ```
- Save the file, and close the Gedit window.
- Back in the terminal, write the command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Wait for the prompt then write:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install alsa-hda-realtek-patched-dkms
  ```
- When this command finishes, reboot.
- After rebooting, test the sound using: System Settings -> Sound -> Test Sound

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

My reference (lindis) was the post n.17 of the site  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1037763.

Comment: If you need to edit your answer, you can do so. You can also leave comments on questions and answers. This isn't a forum, answers won't stay in the same order necessarily, so posts like this are confusing.